# .htaccess rewrite from subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Any help with this would really be appreciated.

I am setting up 301 redirects in a .htaccess file to redirect hundreds of old urls to the latest live pages.

My .htaccess file is currently located in the root of the domain and looks something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pName=product-one$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pName=product-two$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pName=completely-different-name$
RewriteRule ^catalog/product_info.php$ http://www.mydomain.com/new-product-name-p-123.html? [R=301,L]
```

While researching for answers on how to bulk redirect to one url using .htaccess, I read that it would wise to change the location of the .htaccess file and place it in the specific directories to which it apply's, so requests to other directories won't even these rules.

So I have placed the .htaccess file in the specific sub directory, which is catalog, but the redirect no longer works. What am I missing here? I want the rules for the urls to be redirected to be placed in the .htaccess file inside the catalog folder so all those rewrite rules wont be loaded each time the root .htaccess is loaded.

Comment: I also have OScommerce so I'm checking the specific example.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do. Can you better explain?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you change your redirect 301 line to contain the path directly to you catalog folder of OSCommerce.

So instead of using

```
RewriteRule ^catalog/product_info.php$ http://www.mydomain.com/new-product-name-p-123.html? [R=301,L]
```

use e.g.:

```
Redirect 301 /website/catalog http://www.mydomain.com/page2.htm
```

or

```
Redirect 301 /catalog http://www.mydomain.com/page2.htm
```

Option 1) is if your catalog is located at http://youdDomain.com/website/catalog/ .
If it is located at http://youdDomain.com/website/aaa/catalog/ you would use:

```
Redirect 301 /website/aaa/catalog http://www.mydomain.com/page2.htm
```

I tested this in my own webserver - hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you put the .htaccess in a subdirectory, you must adjust the `RewriteRule` pattern accordingly. mod_rewrite strips the directory prefix, where the .htaccess file is located, see [`RewriteRule - What is matched?`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).

You must change the rule to

```
RewriteRule ^product_info.php$ ...
```

If you have lots of URL paths to rewrite, you might also want to look into [`RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap).